# Translating "Help!" (interjection)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, interjecciones, vocabulario

In English, if there is any kind of emergency or urgent assistance needed, we use the interjection, "Help!" In Spanish I've seen several:

- *¡Socorro!*
- *¡Auxilio!*
- *¡Ayuda!* or *¡Ayúdame!*

Which of these is the most general-purpose word used in emergencies? Is there any difference between these Spanish interjections?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Spain, all of them are very common, and use one of them is just a question of regional/personal preferences.

To me, 'socorro' and 'auxilio' sounds more urgent and important than 'ayuda', probably because 'socorro' and 'auxilio' are only used in an emergency, while 'ayuda' is also related to non-urgent help.

Answer (score 6):

In Mexico the most common are:

- ¡Ayuda!
- ¡Ayúdame!
- ¡Ayúdenme!

We understand `socorro` and `auxilio` but they are not used daily.

Comment: Sounds like the same as in Argentina.

Answer (score 1):

> Ayuda = Help
>
> Ayúdame = Help me
>
> Socorro = Ask for help;(any one for help...)
>
> Auxilio = Aid, assistance